# Sliding of subnav doesn't work

Tags: jquery, slideup

Something is wrong with my code, because the `level_1` and `level_2` subnav doesn't slide on click.
For example: if I click on the `h2` the sub nav `level_1` and if I click on the `li` with parent `level_1` the `level_2` subnav will slide down.

### Javascript

```
$('.nav_item > h2').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
        $('.nav_item ul').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $('.nav_item ul).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sT3TC/5/

Comment: add css into jsfiddle

Comment: fiddle doesnt seem to be working

Comment: I changes som css and js but its stil not working http://jsfiddle.net/sT3TC/4/

Comment: I updated my question the sub nav wont slide

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

### CSS:

```
.wrap {display: none;}
.active {color: blue;}
```

### jQuery:

```
$('.nav_item > h2').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
        var wrap = $(this).next();
        $('.wrap').not(wrap).slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $('.nav_item > h2').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sT3TC/7/)**

Comment: Thank you but but the "level_2" subnav should only be displayed when i click on the li withe the class "submenu", how can i do that?

Comment: I tried to change the slideUp class ".wrap > ul > .level_1" but now somethings wrong withe the toggle effect: http://jsfiddle.net/sT3TC/8/

Answer (score 0):

You missed a bracket on your jsFiddle, please find the correct on the updated jsFiddle.

Clearly I don't believe you are pointing to the right DOM resource inside your if statement. You can consider changing to

```
$(this).find('ul')
```

[jQuery find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

http://jsfiddle.net/sT3TC/6/